# PHP - Correct way to get current UTC date time

Tags: php, date, time, timezone, utc

I have searched stack overflow and google and other sources for an answer to this, though, all answers i find are pretty different, the answer that occurred the most (twice) was this one:

```
$time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $time->format('F j, Y H:i:s');
```

So my question is, is that the best/correct way to get the current UTC date/time, and if not, what is?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is one of the ways to get the current UTC time. I would recommend sticking with the DateTime API in general as it provides all sort of useful functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure where the examples you have found come from, but `gmdate` is almost certainly the best way to get the correct GMT date and time from the current time, or a supplied timestamp.

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php):

> Identical to the date() function except that the time returned is
>   Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

Usage to get the current GMT date time:

```
echo gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s");
```

Usage with an existing timestamp:

```
echo gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

The date value supplied is automatically adjusted from the local timezone to GMT.

Obviously, the format of the date can be changed to whatever you wish by modifying the first parameter.

Comment: As the questioner specifically asked for UTC, GMT is not correct as for 6 months of the year as it doesn't exist. It is replaced with BST, or GMT+01:00.

Comment: @RichardAQuadling Actually, the date is formatted to _GMT\UTC_.  GMT is not a reference to British timekeeping which (which you referenced).  GMT and UTC are the same thing and the UK happens to sit within the GMT timezone but is shifted by BST twice a year.  Ref docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

Comment: @RichardAQuadling From the Wikipedia article about GMT: "_English speakers often use GMT as a synonym for Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)._".  You are talking about the UK time zone and not GMT. Thanks for the downvote though.